# How to set distance between nodes in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, nodes, tikz-node

I'm trying to draw a web graph for a paper, using TikZ to draw the individual pages as nodes. When I typeset, however, the graph sits in one small corner of the line, and the nodes are too close together. `node distance` doesn't work, and `minimum size` just expands the nodes such that they overlap each other. How can I set the minimum distance between the nodes? Thanks.

The unfinished (no lines yet) graph looks like this:

[image]

Ideally, it should be the width of the page and the nodes should be distributed farther away from each other.

My code looks like this:

```
 \documentclass[12pt, oneside]{amsart}      
\usepackage{geometry}                       
\geometry{a4paper}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{node}=[circle, draw=black!100, thick]
\tikzstyle{dangling node}=[circle, draw=black!100, fill=black!30, thick]
\begin{tikzpicture}[minimum size=5mm][node distance=5.3cm,>=stealth?,bend angle=45,auto]
  \node[node](page 1){1};
  \node[node](page 2)[right of=page 1]{2};
  \node[node](page 3)[below of=page 1]{3};
  \node[node](page 4)[below of=page 2]{4};
  \node[dangling node](page 5)[below of=page 3, xshift=5mm]{5};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try the syntax `right=10mm of page 1` (instead of `right of`).

Comment: Hmm, I tried it, but latex gave me the error that 'of' was not defined.

Comment: I forgot `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}`

Comment: You have `\begin{tikzpicture}[<options1>][<options 2>]`, while you should have `\begin{tikzpicture}[<options 1>,<options 2>]`.

Comment: Wow, I didn't think that would work. Thanks! I thought that the multiple option blocks made no difference. One interesting thing is that when I combine the options, the code that worked before returned an error saying `=>stealth?` was undefined due to the `?` sign, even though it worked fine when in two option blocks. Do you know why this happens? @TorbjørnT.

Comment: The second block of options is just ignored altogether I think.

Comment: Another way to increase node spacing is to use [outer sep=...] or [every node/.style={outer sep=...}].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `tikzpicture` environment only takes *one* optional argument. I.e., if LaTeX sees a `[` after `\begin{tikzpicture}`, it grabs everything up to the first `]` it sees, and that is the options for the environment. When you have `\begin{tikzpicture}[..][..]`, the second bracket pair is actually just read as normal text I think, and TiKZ generally tries to suppress anything that isn't a `pgf`/TikZ command, so it is basically ignored.

So in summary, all the options for a `tikzpicture` has to be placed in the same bracket pair.

If you change your code accordingly (and remove the misplaced `?` after `stealth`), you will find that your `node distance` setting works as expected.

That said, you might want to follow TeXnicians advice to use the `positioning` library, and say e.g. `right=of` instead of `right of=`. Some discussion on this is found in [Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9386/difference-between-right-of-and-right-of-in-pgf-tikz).
Another reason for using the `positioning` library is that you can set the horizontal and vertical node distances separately, by writing `node distance=Ycm and Xcm`, an example is seen in the code below. As gernot mentions in a comment, in that case one would probably also want to add `on grid` to the node style. `on grid` means that the distances are calculated from the center point of the nodes.

Final note: you can put one style inside another, so if `dangling node` has the same style as `node`, with the addition of the `fill`, then you can say `dangling node/.style={node,fill=black!30}`. This reduces code duplication, and makes it easier to modify.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry}                       
\geometry{a4paper}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{
  node/.style={circle, draw=black!100, thick, on grid}, % on grid added
  dangling node/.style={node, fill=black!30}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  minimum size=5mm,
  node distance=4cm and 7cm,
  >=stealth,
  bend angle=45,
  auto
]
  % grid to easier see that the node centers line up  
  \draw [help lines] (-1,-9) grid (9,1);

  \node[node](page 1){1};
  \node[node](page 2)[right=of page 1]{22};
  \node[node](page 3)[below=of page 1]{3333};
  \node[node](page 4)[below=of page 2]{4555555};
  \node[dangling node](page 5)[below=of page 3, xshift=5mm]{5};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should probably add the option `on grid` such that the nodes really line up.

Comment: @gernot Fair point, edited.

Comment: Why `node distance=` has two values? is the second one is for the y-axis?

Comment: @alper "Another reason for using the positioning library is that you can set the horizontal and vertical node distances separately, by writing `node distance=Ycm and Xcm` ..."